# How to stop infinite css animation at end frame with pure css or least js involved?

Tags: html, css, animation

I know we can stop a finite css animation via `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`. However, how to achieve the same effects for infinite animations? For example, for the following snippets, when `pointerup` is fired, how to stop the animation at `360deg` state?

```js
document.addEventListener("pointerup", () => {
  const div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
  // 
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  animation: ani 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes ani {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

### Appendix:

1. I know we can use timer in JS, and check whether `pointerup` is raised in each timer interval, however a solution with pure css or least js involved is preferred.
2. We should ensure the solution works well in modern browsers, such as Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge.

Comment: `animation: ani 5s linear;` ?

Answer (score 0):

try this link

[Stop infinite CSS3 animation and smoothly revert to initial state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35507472/stop-infinite-css3-animation-and-smoothly-revert-to-initial-state)

You will get idea how to do so. Works fine for me.

Comment: Thank you Rahul! Listening to `animationiteration` event perfectly solved my issue! Could you please elaborate your answer then I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
div.addEventListener("pointerup", (ev) => {
  ev.target.className = "stopme";
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  animation: ani 5s infinite;
}

div.stopme{
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@keyframes ani {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however this doesn't work when current iteration is > 1 (which will cause animation stops directly), ans also, it doesn't work in Microsoft Edge, though seems like a bug in Edge.