# Transition right after animation

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

On my element, I have a CSS animation running as long as it has a certain class (`wiggle`), and a transition as soon as it has a different one (`right`):

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner wiggle"></div>
</div>
```

```
@keyframes wiggle {
  from {
    left: 10%;
  }
  50% {
    left: 30%;
  }
  to {
    left: 10%;
  }
}

.inner {
  left: 0;

  &.wiggle {
    animation: wiggle 2s infinite;
  }

  &.right {
    left: 90%;
    transition: left 2s;
  }
}
```

Now, if remove the `wiggle` class and add `right` at the same time, the transition doesn't play out; `left: 90%` applies immediately. However, if there's a delay between removing the former and adding the latter, the transition will happen as expected.

**[Here's a JSFiddle illustrating the issue.](https://jsfiddle.net/aws9gcw9/12/)**

It looks like when coming from an animation, values (such as `left` in this case) don't have an explicit value to transition from, so they're just rendered to their final state.

Is this expected behavior, i.e. is it part of a specification? Or are browsers free how to handle that case?

*I've tested on the lastest versions of Firefox and Chromium.*

---

*Clarification:* **I'm not mainly looking for workarounds, especially not complicated ones, but more for a reason *why* exactly browsers behave like they do.**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33652438/9288348, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33829469/css-transition-after-animation-ends?noredirect=1&lq=1 I think they had the same problem.

Comment: I think this may be a bug in browser rendering or so, but If you want a solution I can give you one with `transform`.!

Comment: @Jeremy the first one looks like it's caused by the same behavior, but not exactly the same problem, and the second is slightly different, at least it's solution it's applicable in my case.

Comment: @weBBer Well, I'm trying to do similar things with other properties too, `left` was just easiest to visualize and isolate the issue. For example, there's no such workaround for `opacity`.

Comment: @CedricReichenbach I didn't mean the same problem, sorry. But I ment that it both kinda had the same cause. Since you can't have `animation ` and `transition` on the same element.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be a bug in browser rendering or so, but If you want a solution I can give you one alternative method with `transform`

A working fiddle for you:

```js
$('#toggle').click(() => {
  $('.inner').removeClass('wiggle').addClass('right');
});
```

```css
@keyframes wiggle {
  from {
    left: 10%;
  }
  50% {
    left: 30%;
  }
  to {
    left: 10%;
  }
}

.outer {
  height: 5em;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(0%);
  background-color: green;
  transition: transform 2s ease-in-out;
}

.inner.wiggle {
  animation: wiggle 2s infinite;
}

.inner.right {
  transform: translate(900%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>
  Animated
</h2>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner wiggle"></div>
</div>
<h2>
  Not animated
</h2>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<hr>
<button id="toggle">
move right
</button>
```

I hope this was helpful for you.

Comment: As mentioned in my other comment, this is just a workaround using other CSS properties. However, I'm looking for a general solution working for any property.

Comment: @CedricReichenbach got it bro. may someone bring you a common solution so it may also help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Its look it is the expected behavior. I think when you are adding the `right` class with `left:90%`, its not able to pick the starting value for the `left` css property. As an alternate you can create another keyframe for the `.right` class

```js
$('#toggle').click(() => {
  $('.inner').removeClass('wiggle').addClass('right');
});
```

```css
@keyframes wiggle {
  0% {
    left: 10%;
  }
  50% {
    left: 30%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 10%;
  }
}

@keyframes right {
  100% {
    left: 90%;
  }
}

.outer {
  height: 5em;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-color: green;
  transition: left 2s;
}

.wiggle {
  animation: wiggle 2s infinite;
}

.right {
  animation: right 2s forwards;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>
  Animated
</h2>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner wiggle"></div>
</div>
<h2>
  Not animated
</h2>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<hr>
<button id="toggle">
move right
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This workaround might help you, the idea is to use the [css variables](https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20variables), the idea is to set the animation with an alternate function, so in this way we will only need From and To... on the other hand we need to set up and event for every iteration, in that way we know when an iteration ends,

So when we click the button you can change the variable value and remove the class...

```js
$('#toggle').click(() => {
  $('.inner').addClass('right');
});
let flag = false;
$(".inner").on("animationiteration webkitAnimationIteration oAnimationIteration MSAnimationIteration", function(){ 
  flag && $(".inner").removeClass('wiggle');
  if($(".inner").hasClass('right')) flag = true;  
});
```

```css
:root {
     --from: 10%;
     --to: 30%;
   }
   
   
@keyframes wiggle {
  from {
    left: var(--from);
  }

  to {
    left: var(--to);
  }
}

.outer {
  height: 5em;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(0%);
  background-color: green;
  transition: transform 2s ease-in-out;
  left:90%;
}

.inner.wiggle {
  left:10%;
  animation: wiggle 1s infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

.inner.right {
  --to:90%;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-duration:2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>
  Animated
</h2>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner wiggle"></div>
</div>
<hr>
<button id="toggle">
move right
</button>
```

Consider that this has a bug when the animation is moving back to the start point...

Comment: Hmm, interesting approach; so instead of disabling the animation, we just alter it. However, it's still a workaround and pretty complex. I'm not mainly looking for a perfect workaround, but more for a reason why exactly it behaves as it does.